# Using he/she when speaking quickly

Tags: english, speaking, grammatical-gender

I am reasonably fluent with English and can express arbitrary thoughts by using it. However, when speaking fast, I often use the wrong pronoun (from "he" or "she"). I am also aware of "they", which I have not misused thus far.

I have no problem understanding the difference between "he" and "she". I do not make the mistake when I have time, or when I write. The probable reason for the problem is that Finnish, my native language, has only one gender-neutral word "hän", not separate words for males and females.

How do I learn to not make this mistake anymore?

Answer (score 3):

I have a Persian-speaking friend, and he has the same issue, because Persian only has a neutral 3rd person singular pronoun. He still makes the mistake occasionally, but in the end it's just practice, practice, practice. I bet there are native English-speaking tutors in Finland that know exactly how to put you through drills that will focus your practice. So if I were you, I would try to find one of these Finland-based tutors, because this is surely a common problem that they deal with everyday.

EDIT: If you aren't physically in Finland, just use Skype (or equivalent) to get the help of one of these tutors.

Comment: I do not live in Finland at the moment and most Norwegians probably do not have this problem.

Comment: Yes, but Skype works everywhere there is internet :)